# Move elements in an object array in front of a different element [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm doing an assignment and I was wondering if there was an easy to move elements in an array around. I'm trying to sort a list of authors alphabetically, so I'd like to compare array[1] to array[2] and if 2 belongs in front of 1 I'd simply like to move it there. I figured the best way to do this would be by using two for loops. Here's basically what I have. Is there any easy way to move k in front of j in the array?

```
for(int j = 0; i > j; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k > i; k++) {
                if(array[j].getAuthor.compareTo(array[k]) == -1) {
                    //move k in front of j
                } else {
                                  //do nothing
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you use java, so the jdk provides a method for you.

```
Arrays.sort(array,new Comparator<Object> {
      @Override
      public int compare(final Object pre, final Object next){
        //return 0, 1 ,-1 
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive "move in front of" operation on Java arrays.

What you need to do is to rethink your algorithm so that it works using the primitive operations that ARE available to you.  These are<sup>*</sup> getting and setting the element at a particular offset (using `array[i]`), and getting the length of the array (using `array.length`).

So if you want to put `array[i]` in front of `array[j]` you need to move all of the elements between `i` and `j` to the left or right using a loop and assignments.  I'll leave you to work out the details ... 'cos that is obviously what the person who set your homework expects you to do.

---

<sup>* - actually, there are a couple of library methods for bulk copying array elements; e.g. `System.arraycopy`.  However, I recommend that you implement it with loops so that you can get a better understanding of what is involved.</sup>

Comment: Would I not be able to create a temporary object of the same type. Assign all the values of j to the temporary object. Assign all the values of k to j. Then assign all the temporary objects values to k?